# xa_commit failed when trying to commit jms transaction

Tags: oracle, jms, websphere, ibm-mq, xa

We are trying to write a message to a broker queue. But the whole request fails when it tries to commit the JMS transaction & then it tries to rollback each subsequent time. We use oracle XA drivers. Not sure where to post this issue: MQ forums or Oracle forum. So thought would give a try here. Can someone help resolve this please.

Error:

```
[9/25/12 17:10:06:871 EDT] 0000003e XATransaction E   J2CA0027E: An exception occurred while invoking commit on an XA Resource Adapter from dataSource JMS$QCF$JMSManagedConnection@23, within transaction ID {XidImpl: formatId(57415344), gtrid_length(36), bqual_length(54), data(00000139ff43ef2500000001000043106c82332ef6bc723402e84f341fb357080ddd4d1b00000139ff43ef2500000001000043106c82332ef6bc723402e84f341fb357080ddd4d1b000000010000000000000000000000000001)}: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_commit' has failed with errorCode '-7'.
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource.commit(JmqiXAResource.java:407)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedSession$JMSXAResource.commit(JMSManagedSession.java:1702)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.commit(XATransactionWrapper.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.JTAXAResourceImpl.commit_one_phase(JTAXAResourceImpl.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.RegisteredResources.flowCommitOnePhase(RegisteredResources.java:2916)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TransactionImpl.commitXAResources(TransactionImpl.java:2533)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1687)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1647)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:1582)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:293)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1002)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:901)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run(DelegatingWork.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:264)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.CJWorkItemImpl.run(CJWorkItemImpl.java:187)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1560)
.
[9/25/12 17:10:06:880 EDT] 0000003e RegisteredRes W   WTRN0052E: An attempt by the transaction manager to call one phase commit on a transactional resource has resulted in an XAER_RMFAIL error. The resource was com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.JTAXAResourceImpl@1d07bf1#{XidImpl: formatId(57415344), gtrid_length(36), bqual_length(54), data(00000139ff43ef2500000001000043106c82332ef6bc723402e84f341fb357080ddd4d1b00000139ff43ef2500000001000043106c82332ef6bc723402e84f341fb357080ddd4d1b000000010000000000000000000000000001)}
[9/25/12 17:10:06:887 EDT] 0000003e DefaultMessag W org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer handleListenerSetupFailure Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:///RANDOM QUEUE?targetClient=1' - trying to recover. Cause: Heuristic completion: outcome state is mixed; nested exception is javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
```

Comment: The answer depends on the app server being used, on what is playing the role of the transaction coordinator, and whether the XA client is installed.  Note that the error indicates a 1-phase commit was called on a transactional resource.  This suggests the BEGIN verb as not called.

Comment: Thanks Rob. The App server is Websphere 6.0 (or 6.1), i guess you are asking about the transaction manager..it is WebSphereUowTransactionManager. Also Where should the XA client be installed? I'm not understanding by what BEGIN verb not being called. Can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, Harish I may have led you a bit astray.  If using the WebSphere App Server, then it has the ability natively to perform XA transactions with MQ. Also, in JMS there's no explicit BEGIN verb. However, there must be some reason that a single-phase commit was called on a transactional resource. Based on the new information, a wild guess would be reuse of sessions across threads where one is XA and one is not. But I'm hoping someone will come up with a definitive answer because I'm just guessing at this point. Please be sure to post the solution when and if you find it.

Comment: Earlier we had multiple JMS sessions. That was probably the cause of the issue in one of the environments. So we had to change to 2 diff. sessions & now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier we had multiple JMS sessions. That was probably the cause of the issue in one of the environments. So we had to change to 2 diff. sessions & now it works!

Julian:

My scenario is slightly different from yours. Earlier we had:

A request message was put on the queue. This queue was picked up & processed. Then we saved to the DB & then generated another message & put it on another broker queue & then sent a response to the first message. All this was 1 flow.

Now we changed that to 2 diff. flows : Request --> Process --> Save to DB --> Reply
and then another flow to put on Broker queue.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508472)'s the cause and resolution

Quote-

> The cause of these errors is usually the result of a WebSphere MQ
>   messaging provider JMS Connection being closed off by WebSphere
>   Application Server because the Aged timeout for the Connection has
>   expired.

Resolution-

> To resolve this issue, ensure that the JMS Connection Factory being
>   used by the application has the Connection Pool property **Aged timeout**
>   set to zero. This will prevent JMS Connections being closed when they
>   are returned to the Free Pool, and so ensures that any outstanding
>   transactional work can be completed

It is sometimes also caused by the faulty DataDirect Driver and is reported and fixed by IBM, see [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC70069).

Comment: We checked that as well earlier. It's already set to zero :(. Thanks so much for your reply. Appreciate a lot. But it doesn't work in this scenario. Thanks again

Comment: I read that there is some problem with `XA_COMMIT` and call and the DataDirect driver in WS Message broker itself. What version of message broker are you using? I will update the answer with another possible link. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks @Annjawn. We do not have access to the broker, but we got the details. The broker version is 6.1 & fix pack 4.

Comment: Also the IBM link shows "In XA transactions involving a flow which updates an Oracle
database and writes to a WMQ output queue, when an Oracle
error occurs the result can be that messages are written to the
queue but not committed to the database." Earlier we were updating the DB, but now we commented it out for testing purposes, but we still get the error. Do you think the fix would still work for our scenario?

Comment: I guess the fix should work irrespective of that. The fix was to fix the datadirect driver which was interpreting `XA_COMMIT` wrong. I guess it wouldn't hurt to apply the patch.

Comment: The problem is as I said earlier, we don't have access to that environment & they need justification to apply the patch!

Comment: Well, your error and [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC70069) IBM article should be justification enough. You can also let them know what steps you took to try resolve this.